# Excel VBA Userform Font color change

Tags: vba, excel

I took over a userform from others (this form is made by Excel VBA). I noticed that guy created two textbox, one's background is in white, another one is in black. However I want to make all the textbox's background in white but I don't know how to change the font color inside of textbox. I want to change font color into black(like the left textbox) of the right textbox showed below. Could anyone help me?Thanks a lot!![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzXLI.png)

Comment: To approach this I would open the file in VBA, then create a new command button.
In the code for the button, use
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 0 This will change the cell A1 to No Fill, or white. You will have to change the code to the specific cell you would like to change to white.
PS: If you can't use VBA send me a message and I will try to help! Visit: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/background-colors.html
or
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-Form-or-a-Control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283

Comment: In the VBA editor (Alt+F11) find your Userform under 'Forms', select the textbox that is black, then right click and select 'Properties'. In there you will find the property to control the text colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the VBA editor and select your textbox.If the properties window on the bottom left of your screen is not visible, hit F4 or select the "View" menu at the top of the editor and select properties window.

With your textbox still selected, the option you need to change the font colour is shown:

[image]

and for the background colour:

[image]

Both colours can be selected on the colour pickup that pops up when you click on the dropdown arrow next to the property, so you dont need to memorise these values.See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In VBE, when you are in UserForm edition, select the textbox you want to change.

You'll find that Properties panel (generally in the bottom left corner of VBE) or right click and *Properties*

You'll need to change `BackColor` and `ForeColor`! ;)

[image]